# Nginx should only listen to specific interface

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to limit some domain access to a certain interface.
Means on the same reverse proxy we have listener for public interfaces and internal interfaces. Some domains should be only available on internal interface. (IPs and domains just as an example)

```
server {
    listen 8.8.8.8:80;
    server_name a.kennsch.io;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 8.8.8.8:443 ssl http2;
        server_name a.kennsch.io;
        ...

server {
  listen 10.124.11.199:80;
  server_name b.kennsch.io;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 10.124.11.199:443 ssl http2;
  server_name b.kennsch.io;
  ...
```

if I open then http://a.kennsch.io i will be redirected to https://b.kennsch.io. Which is only available if VPN is open.

If I remove all interface declarations it works correctly but how can I ensure that b.kennsch.io is only available from internal networks?

Comment: Perhaps your public services should be available on both interfaces, maybe use `*:80` instead of `8.8.8.8:80`

Comment: already tried to only bind b.kennsch.io to an interface and have a.kennsch.io on listen 80; but it behaves the same

Comment: Do you clear the browser cache between tests?

Comment: yes even tried with curl